# I need the accordion to appended element in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

HTML

```
<div id="cluster">
  <div> // some content goes </div>
  <div> // some content goes </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
var content = '<div id="accordion"><h3>Heading</h3><p>Some content</p></div>';

$('#cluster div').click(fn(){
  $('#cluster').append(content);
});
```

Now how can i add accordion to that appended element.

Actually I tried this code to add accordion like this but it is not acting as accordion.

```
$('#accordion').accordion({
  active: false,
  collapsible: true
});
```

Can anyone help how to do that

Comment: When are you running `$('#accordion').accordion(...)`? Maybe the element doesn't exist yet!?

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle with the accordion js setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this : [jsfiddle.net/bharatsing/keqLf315/](https://jsfiddle.net/bharatsing/keqLf315/)

```
$('#cluster div').click(function(){
  var content="<div class='accordion'><h3>Section 1</h3><div>some content goes</div> </div>";
  $('#cluster').append($(content));
  Init();
});

function Init(){
  $('.accordion').accordion({
    active: false,
    collapsible: true
  });
}

Init();
```